# android button causing crash

Tags: android, button

I am trying to pass login details to another class so that it can be used to login on my MySQL db (using php) but it is crashing giving me the exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

stack trace: {StackTraceElement[0]@5692}

658 10752-10752/uk.ac.abertay.contactslist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: uk.ac.abertay.contactslist, PID: 10752
                                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void uk.ac.abertay.contactslist.Login.Logino(uk.ac.abertay.contactslist.LoginDetails)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at uk.ac.abertay.contactslist.LoginActivity.Loginbutton(LoginActivity.java:40)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
04-26 15:39:34.761 1384-3633/? I/chatty: uid=1041(audioserver) writer identical 8 lines

this is the code for the button

```
    private Login login;


   public void Loginbutton(View v) {

    /* Get entered fields data. */
    String email = field_email.getText().toString();
    String password = field_password.getText().toString();


         login.Logino(new LoginDetails(email,password));



    }
```

when debugging it will run this and go back to the button and after that it will give the exception and crash

```
public class LoginDetails {

   public String email = "";
   public String password = "";

   LoginDetails(String e, String p) {
       email = e;
       password = p;
   }
}
```

this is the code I'm trying to run with the button above

```
public void Logino(LoginDetails loginDetails) {
    LoginTask task = new LoginTask();
    task.execute(loginDetails);
}
```

Comment: Add the rest of the Exception stacktrace

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos added the stack trace inside ex

Comment: That doesn't help, copy the stacktrace printed in the logcat

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos was that what you wanted?

Comment: You passed view then what did u do with it?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos sorry i never showed it but i did declare it, put in on now

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos actually i got it, thanks for the help ill add an answer

Answer (score 0):

From your StackTrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void uk.ac.abertay.contactslist.Login.Logino(uk.ac.abertay.contactslist.LoginDetails)
```

The line `login.Logino` the object login is null, you have to initialize it.

Obs:Please use Java naming conventions with method names starting with low case char.

Comment: Please don't post answers on questions that you vote to close. Closing means no answers can be posted, so that's basically you trying to prevent others from answering after you have.

Comment: Haaa.. good point Mike, next time only comments